# jQuery change not working with datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have some fields on my page that use the bootstrap datepicker and set like so:

```
$(".datepicker-input").each(function () { $(this).datepicker(); });
```

Obviously they have that class if I want them to be a datepicker.  On some of the field I want to run a function based on them so I implemented the change event for jquery:

```
$(".eventfilter").change(function () {
    self.loadEvents();
});
```

Again done like this so I just set a class for each.  Only issue is for all the selects, checkboxes, texts it all works except for any text inputs that use the datepicker.  It might be because these ones are also set to readonly so a user can't put in an invalid date.

Any quick ideas on how to trigger the change event for these, baring in mind I don't want it for all datepickers/fields just on the ones with the class eventfilter.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you're asking here...

Comment: Basically after changing the input via the datepicker the change event doesn't run.  I need to know how I can trigger the change after the datepicker is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
// OnChange event
$(".eventfilter").on('change', function () {
    // Some code here
});

// Trigger onChange event via javascript
$(".eventfilter").trigger('change');
```

You can run it manually after selecting date via datepicker. Here a full list of datepicker events http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/. For example:

```
$(".datepicker-input").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        $(".eventfilter").trigger('change');
    }
});
```

Comment: I now know I can do that but where would I put the code to trigger the change, somewhere in the datepicker initialisation?

Answer (score -1):

To anyone else this may help I had to set the datepicker for these fields differently to trigger the function after the datepickers changeDate event:

```
$('.eventdatepicker-input').datepicker()
                    .on('changeDate', function(e){
                        self.loadEvents();
                });
```

Comment: Why do you give answer for bootstrap datepicker? TS ask about jquery dp.